# NSFetchedResultsController with NSPredicate "SELF IN %@" works only after app-restart

Tags: ios, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UITableViewController (TVC) with NSFetchResultsController (frc) filling it. Here's the initialization of frc:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)frc
{
    if (!_frc)
    {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:e_product];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"product_group.product_group_name" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];                
    _frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.moc sectionNameKeyPath:@"product_group.product_group_name" cacheName:nil];
    _frc.delegate = self;
    NSError *error;
    if (![_frc performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@!", error.userInfo);
    }
    if (_frc.sections.count < 1)
    {
        // looks like the product list is empty!
        [self refreshProductCatalog];
    }
}
return _frc;
}
```

It works just fine: when TVC is displayed, frc performs fetch for the first time, sees that there're no "product" entities and requests them with refreshProductCatalog. After new entities were added, frc "feels" it and reloads the TVC item gracefully (self is a delegate if TVC).

The problem appears when I add the predicate to the FetchRequest:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", someManagedObject.setOfProductsEntities];
```

I fill someManagedObject.setOfProductsEntities in refreshProductCatalog with proper entities (I'm sure because it works fine after restart). The problem is that when the predicate is in place, frc doesn't "feel" the change in managed object context after I change the data and doesn't reload TVC. If I leave the TVC and open it again (or restart the app) everything is fine, the data was already saved...

Any clues what is wrong here?
Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

To get full tracking of changes, the cache name should not be nil.  The other thing I have done wrong in the past is to assign a delegate but forget to implement a delegate method.

Comment: Delegate methods are in place. I copied them from Apple example and they work well for another TVC with no predicates. Funny thing: tried to change the cacheName to `@"Root"` and now I don't see fetched products even after app restart. And even when I changed it back to `nil` and removed the physical file where I stored the data in simulator - it doesn't work ;))

Comment: OK, I rolled back all the changes I made after posting the question and now I'm back to the starting point: the TVC is populated with appropriate Products only after TVC reload or app restart. Adding `@"Root"` as cacheName didn't help. Do I need to do something more than just put this name in when creating NSFetchedResultsController?